# Can I change the colour or highlight cell in excel using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Hey everyone just checking if I can highlight a cell using nodejs when writing to an .csv

I am writing to it fine just want to highlight the headings.

Comment: A csv does not retain format, at least not that I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no formatting in a CSV. It's a barebones text file.

Comment: Thanks thats what I am realising